# NLP-Problem, language model BERT?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, bert, language-model

Right now I am in the process of deciding on my masters thesis topic. Right now I and my professor are thinking about the possibility of having a large dataset of product requirements given in a natural language. My task would be to develop a domain-specific language (DSL) for these requirements and afterwards to develop a neural network that gets the dataset containing these requirements as an input and transforms each requirement into a requirement in this DSL that I have to develop beforehand.

In theory a topic which I personally find very interesting and would love to learn more about, the only problem is, my current knowledge in this area is very limited so I am trying to read up on it right now.

An example for such a DSL would be presented in this Paper: [A Textual Domain Specific Language for Requirement Modelling](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281372036_A_Textual_Domain_Specific_Language_for_Requirement_Modelling)
(It's not exactly the same but a good showcase of the DSL might be derived from it).

For the people that don't want to read the paper there is an example given like this:

`Natural Language Req: "The Lateral and Vertical 'ERC' and'WRD' labels shall be displayed in a green color"`

The neural network should then take this requirement as an input and generate the following requirements:

Req1: **The** Lateral_ERC_Label **shall be displayed in** green

Req2: **The** Lateral_WRD_Label **shall be displayed in** green

Req3: **The** Vertical_ERC_Label **shall be displayed in** green

Req4: **The** Vertical_WRD_Label **shall be displayed in** green

As we can see the DSL, in this case, has the keywords "The" and "shall be displayed in" (Bolded) that stay the same for each generated requirement, and in between are the specifications for the requirement.

Now the question is, how is this achievable? Or rather, is this achievable at all? My professor said I should look into BERT for this task but my research has led me to the conclusion that BERT is not really suitable for text generation.

On the other hand, I am not really sure if this above-mentioned problem can be classified as text generation. It looks like a combination problem of text extraction (extracting the necessary keywords) and text generation.

But I am not really sure if I am even looking and researching in the right direction right now. So I would really appreciate it if somebody would be able to help me out here and giving me a push in the right direction.